# Performing an inductive proof

Tags: proof

I have an expression which depends on a variable n and am certain it evaluates to 1 for all n with n=1/2,1,3/2,...

I want to do an inductive proof that this is true but the actual formula is too messy so want mathematica to do it for me. Say the sum depending on n is f[n]. How do I impose the required conditions on f[n] and get it to check for f[n+1/2]?

```
f[n_]=(1/(4 n)!)(-1)^(1 + 2 n) I^(1 + 4 n) ((2 n)!)^2 Pochhammer[-2 n - I (\[Theta][1] -\[Theta][2]), 
1 + 4 n] \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k[1] = 0\), \(2\ n\)]\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k[2] = 0\), \(2\ n\)]\((\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-1\))\),\(\(-1\) - 2\ n - k[1] + k[2]\)]\ \*SuperscriptBox[\(I\), \(\(-4\)\ n\)]\ \((\(-I\)\ \((k[1] - k[2])\) + \[Theta][1] - \[Theta][2])\)\ \*SuperscriptBox[\((I\ \((2\ n -k[1] - k[2])\) + \[Theta][          1] + \[Theta][2])\), \(4\ n\)])\)/\((\(\((2\ n - 
     k[1])\)!\)\ \(k[1]!\)\ \(\((2\ n - k[2])\)!\)\ \(k[
    2]!\)\ Pochhammer[\(-k[2]\) + 
    I\ \((\[Theta][1] - \[Theta][2])\), 
   1 + 2\ n]\ Pochhammer[\(-k[1]\) - I\ \[Theta][1] + 
    I\ \[Theta][2], 1 + 2\ n])\)\)\)
```

Copying and pasting this into mathematica gives the correct function.

As you can test, setting n=1/2,1,3/2,... does indeed give 1. But I dont think mathematica can show this in general.

[Theta][1] and [Theta][2] are fixed complex numbers. k[1] and k[2] are just summation parameters, each one is summed between 0 and 2n.

Comment: Please post the equation in copyable form.

Comment: Please post code as input text (Edit>Copy As).

Comment: There are undefined functions (`k` & `\[Theta]`) in your definition of `f`.

Comment: Fixed @Karsten7.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[n_] := Sin[n Pi]^2

Assuming[n ∈ Integers, Simplify[f[1/2] == f[n + 1/2] == 1]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Or

```
Solve[f[1/2] == f[n + 1/2] == 1, n, Integers]
```

> ```
> {{n -> ConditionalExpression[C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]}}
> ```

Or

```
Reduce[f[1/2] == f[n + 1/2] == 1, n, Integers]
```

> ```
> C[1] ∈ Integers && n == C[1]
> ```

Comment: I've added the actual function to my first post. Unfortunately your method is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

One example: we wish to prove that the $n$th triangular number is $n(n+1)/2$.  We know the recurrence relation:

$$
f(n) = f(n-1) + n
$$

To check that our expression is correct, we simply substitute it in to our relation, like so:

```
f[n] == f[n - 1] + n /. {f -> (# (# + 1)/2 &)}
(* 1/2 n (1 + n) == n + 1/2 (-1 + n) n *)
```

Then we can use `Reduce` to check that the above statement holds:

```
Reduce[%]
(* True *)
```

You'll just use your specific inductive relation, with `f[n + 1/2] == g[f[n],n]` or something similar.

Side note: you may be able to use `RSolve` to get the closed-form expression, like this:

```
f[n] /. RSolve[f[n] == f[n - 1] + n && f[0] == 0, f, n]
(* {1/2 n (1 + n)} *)
```

(Note that to find the solution, you need to provide the base case(s), in this case `f[0] == 0`.)